# Tabularx is repeating table 3 times, not sure why

Tags: tabularx

```
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\caption{Realized matching rate for time pressure group \label{table:timepressuresadvantage}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{lllll}
&&NoB & Matching rate \\ Nash mixed prediction &  && $0.071$ \\ Matching game &Local control& 559 & 0.64(0.006)\\ &Online control& 458 &  0.63(0.004)\\ &Online time-pressure& 388 & 0.63(0.005)\\ Hider-seeker game &Local control& 1060 &  0.09(0.002)\\ &Online control& 893 & 0.09(0.002)\\&Online time-pressure& 753 &  0.15(0.003)\\
\end{tabularx}
\\This table illustrates the realized seeking win rate in normal condition(6s) vs time pressure condition (2s), along with the standard error in the bracket.} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: a tabularx with no X column is always wrong, but it should not repeat. However we can not debug fragments. please edit your question to have a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: `Runaway argument?
{\protect \numberline {\csname the\@captype \endcsname }{\ignorespaces \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.13 ...g with the standard error in the bracket.}
                                                  
? ` After _any_ error  do not even look at the pdf, it is not intended to be usable. You should ask about the error message not the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ignore error messages. You had a missing `}` after the caption and a spurious `}` at the end.  It does not give an error but `tabularx` can do nothing useful with no `X` columns, so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\caption{Realized matching rate for time pressure group \label{table:timepressuresadvantage}}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}Xll}
&&NoB & Matching rate \\
Nash mixed prediction &  && $0.071$ \\
Matching game &Local control& 559 & 0.64(0.006)\\
&Online control& 458 &  0.63(0.004)\\
&Online time-pressure& 388 & 0.63(0.005)\\
Hider-seeker game &Local control& 1060 &  0.09(0.002)\\
&Online control& 893 & 0.09(0.002)\\
&Online time-pressure& 753 &  0.15(0.003)\\
\end{tabularx}

This table illustrates the realized seeking win rate in normal condition(6s) vs time pressure condition (2s), along with the standard error in the bracket.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it moved the table in the doc so I couldn't find it but this now works.